dart http/dio doesn't return the same response as python requests
This is my Dart code using dio, trying to get the result of a  post request, the call itself works, but there seams to be missing data compared to the equivalent python code.
Dart code:
var imageBytes = await inputImage!.readAsBytes();
    try {
      final response = await dio.post(
        url,
        data: Stream.fromIterable(imageBytes.map((e) => [e])),
        options: Options(
          headers: {
            HttpHeaders.contentLengthHeader: imageBytes.length,
          },
        ),
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 202 || response.statusCode == 200) {
        var operationLocation = response.headers['Operation-Location']?.first;
        if (operationLocation == null) {
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print("Operation-Location header not found.");
          }
          return {"error": "Operation-Location header not found"};
        }

        var resultStatus = '';
        Response? resultResponse;

        for (var i = 0; i < maxAttempts; i++) {
          // resultResponse = await dio.get(operationLocation, options: Options(headers: headers));
          resultResponse = await dio.get(operationLocation!);
          resultStatus = resultResponse.data['status'];

          if (resultStatus == 'succeeded' || resultStatus == 'failed') {
            break;
          }
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print("Sleeping polling time");
          }
          await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: pollingInterval));
        }

        if (resultStatus == 'succeeded' && resultResponse != null) {
          var analysisResults = resultResponse.data;
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print("Analysis Results: $analysisResults");
          }
          return analysisResults;
        } else {
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print("Analysis failed.");
          }
          return {"error": "Analysis failed"};
        }
      } else {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print("Unexpected status code: ${response.statusCode}");
        }
        return {"error": "Unexpected status code: ${response.statusCode}"};
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("Failed to send initial POST request: $e");
      }
      return {"error": "Exception occurred: $e"};
    } finally {
      dio.close();
    }

Python code:
session = requests.Session()
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
    "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": key
}

with open(file_path, 'rb') as image_file:
    image_data = image_file.read()

    # Send the initial POST request with the image data
    try:
        response = session.post(url, headers=headers, data=image_data)
        response.raise_for_status()

        if response.status_code in [202, 200]:
            operation_location = response.headers.get('Operation-Location')

            # Poll the Operation-Location URL
            for _ in range(MAX_ATTEMPTS):
                try:
                    result_response = session.get(operation_location, headers=headers)
                    result_response.raise_for_status()

                    result_status = result_response.json().get('status')
                    if result_status in ['succeeded', 'failed']:
                        break
                    print("Sleeping polling time")
                    time.sleep(POLLING_INTERVAL)
                except requests.RequestException as e:
                    print(f"Request error during polling: {e}")
                    break
                except json.JSONDecodeError:
                    print("Error decoding JSON from polling response")
                    break

            # If the operation succeeded, process the results
            if result_status == 'succeeded':
                analysis_results = result_response.json()
                print("Analysis Results:", analysis_results)
            else:
                print("Analysis failed.")
        else:
            print(f"Unexpected status code: {response.status_code}")
            print(response.text)
    except requests.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Failed to send initial POST request: {e}")
    finally:
        session.close()
   

Notice the values here:
Python has rowCount of 42, and 247 cells:

And dart - 40 rowCount and 201 cells.

How can I match these calls to be identical?
